# What are the default access rights for a process started with ShellExecuteEx?

Tags: windows, winapi, shellexecuteex

I need to perform certain operations on a process started with `ShellExecuteEx` - like waiting for it, duplicating handles, querying and setting information etc. Now I am wondering if I can do all these things on the `hProcess` member which is returned in the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure I pass to `ShellExecuteEx`. Does anybody know this?

Does the process that called `ShellExecuteEx` have rights like `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE`, `SYNCHRONIZE`, `PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION`, `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` (and so on) by default, when using the returned `hProcess`?

Comment: Just remember that if the thing you execute is selected by the user, they could select a document or a URL and then you might not get a hProcess at all (DDE,droptarget etc)

Comment: Yep I know, but in my case it is one exactly defined executable file. If there is no handle, something went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that it is the same as what you get from CreateProcess, though even that documentation doesn't say (I would venture PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS).  In any event, you could always do GetProcessId() and OpenProcess() to open it with whatever access you need.

Comment: But wouldn't OpenProcess fail if the started process required elevation (>=Vista)? If the calling process is not elevated it won't have the rights to access the elevated process. But the handle is already there... probably giving access to the elevated process even if the process that called ShellExecuteEx is not elevated?

Comment: I guess it might fail due to integrity levels; I don't remember all the UAC details exactly.  Anyway, there is some documentation on it here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880.aspx) stating the handle returned from CreateProcess() has PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS.  ShellExecuteEx almost certainly gives you that exact handle (or a duplicate of it); unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation that states this explicitly, but it seems extremely likely.

Comment: I think your theory is right, you can do nearly everything with the started process, as long as it has no higher integrity level. Otherwise some rights are not granted (as stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The online time you need to worry about access rights is if you do any task that trigger the uac, then you need to set the `requestedExecutionLevel= 'highestAvailable'`